# Worker process crashes on requests.get() when data is put into input queue before the worker process starts

Tags: python, python-requests, fork, python-multithreading, macos-high-sierra

In macOS High Sierra (Version 10.13.6), I run a Python program that does the following:

- Launches a worker process that consumes data (URL strings) from a `multiprocessing.Queue`.
- The worker process sends HTTP requests with the `requests` package, i.e., it makes `requests.get()` calls.
- Some data (a URL string) is fed to the queue even before the worker process is started.

A program satisfying the above conditions leads to the worker process crashing with this error:

```
objc[24250]: +[__NSPlaceholderDate initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called.
objc[24250]: +[__NSPlaceholderDate initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.
```

I have read the following threads:

- [Multiprocessing causes Python to crash and gives an error may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50168647/303363)
- [Requests module crashes python when numpy is loaded and using process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52014403/303363)
- [Rails: may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52671926/303363)

These threads focus on a workaround for the user. The workaround is defining this environment variable:

```
OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES
```

In this question, I would like to understand why only certain conditions reproduce the error whereas other conditions do not and how to resolve this issue without putting the burden of defining the environment variable `OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES` on the user.

#### Minimal example of the issue

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import requests


def worker(q):
    print('worker: starting ...')

    while True:
        url = q.get()
        if url is None:
            print('worker: exiting ...')
            break

        print('worker: fetching', url)
        response = requests.get(url)
        print('worker: response:', response.status_code)


def master():
    q = mp.Queue()
    p = mp.Process(target=worker, args=(q,))
    q.put('https://www.example.com/')

    p.start()
    print('master: started worker')

    q.put('https://www.example.org/')
    q.put('https://www.example.net/')
    q.put(None)
    print('master: sent data')

    print('master: waiting for worker to exit')
    p.join()
    print('master: exiting ...')


master()
```

Here is the output with the error:

```
$ python3 foo.py 
master: started worker
master: sent data
master: waiting for worker to exit
worker: starting ...
worker: fetching https://www.example.com/
objc[24250]: +[__NSPlaceholderDate initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called.
objc[24250]: +[__NSPlaceholderDate initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead. Set a breakpoint on objc_initializeAfterForkError to debug.
master: exiting ...
```

#### Resolutions

Here are a few independent things I have seen that resolve the issue, i.e., performing only one of these resolves the issue:

1. The issue seems to occur only on using the `requests` package. If we comment out these two lines in `worker()`, it resolves the issue.

   ```
       # response = requests.get(url)
       # print('worker: response:', response.status_code)
   ```
2. The issue seems to occur only if `q.put('https://www.example.com/')` statement occurs before the `p.start()` statement. If we move that statement ater `p.start()`, that resolves the issue.

   ```
       p.start()
       print('master: started worker')

       q.put('https://www.example.com/')
   ```
3. Setting the environment variable `OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES` resolves the issue.

   ```
   OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES python3 foo.py
   ```

#### Non-Resolution

Now, I do not want my users to set a variable name like this to be able to use my tool or API, so I was trying to figure if setting this environment variable within my program could resolve the issue. I found that that adding this to my code does not resolve the issue:

```
import os
os.environ['OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY'] = 'YES'
# Does not resolve the issue!
```

#### Questions

1. Why exactly does this issue occur only under the given conditions, i.e., `requests.get()` and `q.put()` before `p.start()`? In other words, why does the issue disappear if one of these conditions are not met?
2. If we were to expose something like the minimal example as an API function that another developer might call from their code, is there any clever way to resolve this issue in our code, so that the other developer does not have to set `OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES` in their shell before running their program that uses our function?

Of course, a possible solution is to redesign the solution such that we don't have to feed data into the queue before the worker process starts. That's definitely a possible solution. The scope of this question though is to discuss why this issue occurs only when we feed data into the queue *before* the worker process starts.

Comment: `queue.put()` starts a feeder-thread when called first time and forking an already multithreaded application is problematic ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52247576/9059420)). Apparently macOS implements additional safety belts. AFAIK macOS should support alternative process start-methods like "spawn" or "forkserver". Set it via `multiprocessing.set_start_method("spawn")`. Note that for I/O bound workloads it's more usual to just use multithreading instead of multiprocessing anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Great question description! You've got my upvote.

Now for the answer:

- Before macOS 10.13, the objective-C runtime did not support use between `fork()` and `exec()` in the child process of a multithreaded parent process. You could just not call any objective-C method in that interval. This lead to race condition. i.e. most of the time it would work and sometimes it would fail. eg: If a thread in the parent process happened to be holding one of the Object-C runtime's locks when the `fork()` occurred, the child process' would deadlock when it tries to take that lock.
- As of macOS 10.13, the Objective-C runtime now supports use "between" `fork()` and `exec()`. However, there are restrictions involving the `+initialize` methods. (You're problem is in this zone).

Now, before proposing the solution. Let me throw some light around complexity associated with `fork`:

- `fork` creates a copy of the process.
- The child process replaces itself with a different program using the `execve()` system call

So far everything seems OK right?  The child process (`worker` in your case) has a copy of parent's process and this copy is provided to child by `fork()`. *But, `fork()` doesn't copy everything! In particular, it doesn't copy threads. Any threads running in the parent process do not exist in child process*

On that note, focusing on your problem:

Although, macOS 10.13+ supports doing 'anything' between `fork` and `exec`. However, it is very much incorrect to do anything between `fork` and `exec`. In your case, calling `q.put()` before `p.start()` as rightly mentioned by  @Darkonaut starts a feeder-thread when called first time and forking an already multithreaded application is problematic.

This is because `+initialize` methods still have restrictions around `fork()`.The problem is that the thread-safety guarantees of `+initialize` implicitly introduce locks around state that the Objective-C runtime does not control.

When you call `q.put()` or use `requests` library (call into the popular requests library, this will end up calling into the _scproxy module to get the system proxies, and this will end up calling a +initialize method) before `p.start()`, either of them lead your parent process acquiring a lock. You must take note that `fork` creates a copy of process. In your case, when `q.put()` is called before `p.start()`, `fork` happens at the wrong time, and you're `workers` who get a copy of parent's process, get `lock` in copied state.

In you're `worker`, you are doing a `q.get()`. This means acquiring the lock, but the lock is already acquired during `fork` (from parent).

The child process (`worker`) waits for the `lock` to be released but the `lock` would never be released. Because, the thread that would release it wasn't copied over by `fork()`.

There is no good way to make `+initialize` both thread-safe and fork-safe. Instead the Objective-C runtime simply halts the process instead of running any `+initialize` override in the child process:

```
+[SomeClass initialize] may have been in progress in another thread when fork() was called. We cannot safely call it or ignore it in the fork() child process. Crashing instead.
```

Hope that answers your Question 1.

Now, for Question 2:

A few workarounds from best to worse:

1. Do nothing between `fork()` and `exec()` (better not use requests between `fork()` and `exec*()`).
2. Use only async-signal-safe operations between fork() and exec(). The list of those functions available [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html)
3. Define environment variable OBJC_DISABLE_INITIALIZE_FORK_SAFETY=YES, or add a __DATA,__objc_fork_ok section, or build using an SDK older than macOS 10.13. Then cross your fingers.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this same issue on macOS Catalina. I tried to dig deeper requests-library and reason seems to be cryptography-library. Upgrading it solved all problems.

```
pip install cryptography --upgrade  # Version 2.8 worked for me.
```

I had version 2.7 which was producing these objc-errors. Apparently somewhere in that library causes a fork on load and mechanism has been changed in newer version.

Comment: FYI: Python 2.7.16 in use.

Comment: I was getting this error while running the Flask App, your answer was the bull's eye for me

Answer (score 1):

1. I think it's caused by "proxy lookup" mechanism, or some other mac-specific implementation of urllib3 (used internally by python-requests) that causes a fork. Check [github for more info](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1179).
2. Write your function in a such way that it requires "objects that may cause forking on init" as one of the arguments. For example your worker might require a session argument:

```py
def worker(q, session):
    ...

    while True:
        ...
        response = session.get(url)
        print('worker: response:', response.status_code)

def master():
    with requests.Session() as session:  # Or use `session.close()` at the end if you don't like context-manager
        q = mp.Queue()
        p = mp.Process(target=worker, args=(q, session))
        q.put('https://www.example.com/')

        p.start()
        ...
```